# Why import Typescript file with .ts extension increase build time?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, webpacker

I have an angular 11 app compiled by @rails/webpacker. In the pack JS file (`app.js`), I imported my polyfills Typescript (`polyfills.ts`) file like this below, and it takes my `webpack-dev-server` around 3 minutes to finish the build.

```js
import '../../assets/javascripts/polyfills';
```

But when I change that polyfills importing to this below, the build time reduced to 40 seconds from 3 minutes

```js
import '../../assets/javascripts/polyfills.ts';
```

**I wonder why adding the file extension `.ts` in the import statement will reduced the build time?? Is it because the my webpacker takes longer time to resolve the file extension if I don't specify it???**

**Btw**, my `polyfills.ts` looks like this:

```js
import "core-js/features/object/assign";
import "core-js/features/object/keys";
import "core-js/features/object/values";
import "core-js/features/object/is";

import "core-js/features/number/is-integer";
import "core-js/features/number/is-nan";
import "core-js/features/number/parse-float";


import "zone.js/dist/zone";
```

Comment: Enable webpack's trace and see where it's spending time, and come back and paste the report to your question. See here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the suggestion! But the project is using @rails/webpacker, and the webpack's version is still 4.x, which doens't support `stats` yet... Any other ways I can find out what's going on?

But btw, I enabled `pretty: true` in my `webpacker.yml`, and it printed the build progress to the console. It alwasy stuck at 35% progress at a random file (thought it also stuck at 35% when i add the `.ts`, so I don't think it's the reason)

Comment: You can use tools like ProcMon (on Windows), Glances (macOS), and `strace` on Linux to get a general idea of what's going on.

Comment: Could it be that you are triggering some form of an incremental build? I.e. not building the full application but instead rebuilding only parts of it?

Comment: @milo526 No the builds are the same, i only compared the build time when i made sure the build was for the full app.

Comment: @Dai With these tools, i am not able to see the full traces of my webpacker. Besides, I am wondering is this related to the javascript importing syntax? I don't have this issue with `require` as well, it only happened when using `import` withouth `.ts` file extension