# Why is that the webpack build time is faster when importing the polyfills file with .ts extension?

Tags: angularjs, angular, webpack, polyfills, babel-loader

We are working on a multi tenant project which uses `angularjs` and `webpack` with `babel`. Recently we started migrating this project to latest angular version (v11).

The nature of our project is such that we don't use `angular-cli` or `angular.json` for build configurability. Instead we rely on separate `webpack` configuration to build the `node_modules` and our own javascript files. And we use webpack to `bundle` the js pack file for each tenant.

While doing this migration, we had to import `polyfills.ts` file on top of each pack file so that we get the compatibility for older browsers such as IE11.

this is the content of the polyfills.ts

```
// Object
import "core-js/features/object/assign";
import "core-js/features/object/keys";
import "core-js/features/object/values";
import "core-js/features/object/is";

// Number
import "core-js/features/number/is-integer";
import "core-js/features/number/is-nan";
import "core-js/features/number/parse-float";
import "core-js/features/number/parse-int";

// Map
import "core-js/features/map/map-values";

// Array
import "core-js/features/array/every";
import "core-js/features/array/includes";
import "core-js/features/array/fill";
import "core-js/features/array/find";
import "core-js/features/array/find-index";
import "core-js/features/array/from";
import "core-js/features/array/map";
import "core-js/features/array/some";
import "core-js/features/array/filter";

// String
import "core-js/features/string/from-code-point";
import "core-js/features/string/includes";
import "core-js/features/string/starts-with";
import "core-js/features/string/ends-with";

// Set
import "core-js/features/set";

// URL
import "core-js/features/url";

// Promise
import "core-js/features/promise";

// Symbol
import "core-js/features/symbol/async-iterator";
import "core-js/features/symbol/for";
import "core-js/features/symbol/iterator";

// Need this for angular to work
import "zone.js/dist/zone";
```

**Problem**

We recently noticed that after we started importing the `polyfills.ts` at the top the pack file, our local build process started taking significant time to finish. It approximately took 150 seconds to build locally. Plus we needed to increase the `heap-size` of the runtime by 1GB. This change also increased hot reload time intervals where it take more time to refresh the browser after doing a change locally.

**Solution**

After fiddling around with the configuration for so many hours, we found that the solution is to import the polyfills file with the `.ts` extension. This reduced the build time by about 3x. Plus we didn't need to increase the heap-size.

So from below

`import '../../assets/javascripts/polyfills-v2'; // Build time 150 seconds. Also need to increase heap-size`

to

`import '../../assets/javascripts/polyfills-v2.ts'; // Build time now roughly 40 seconds. No need to increase heap-size`

fixed the issue.

However the problem is that we are not 100% sure why adding `.ts` to the import could increase the build time.

**Question**

We have some wild hunches for this behaviour. We think that adding the extension helps `webpack` to identify the file faster during the build time. But we are not 100% convinced about that reason.

So the question is, does anybody have a better idea on why does this happen? Would appreciate any direction on this. While I am happy that this solution works, I cannot think of a convincing reason on how does this solution could improve the build process/time.

Comment: does the bundle size change between solutions?

Comment: Is it the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67188567/why-import-typescript-file-with-ts-extension-increase-build-time?